# Regular Expression for NON delimited email address?

Tags: regex

Outlook 2011 for Mac has a file that contains all the email addresses that you've sent an email to, except it keeps them all in one line with no spaces, for example:

```
email1@company1.com 
email2@company2.co.uk 
email4@company3.net
```

Will actually look like:

```
email1@company1.comemail2@company2.co.ukemail4@company3.net
```

I need to separate these using regex. Normal email regex is no good for this. How can I use regex to look for .com, .co.uk, .net, .org as the separators? I can add more if required.

Comment: Not sure why the vote to close? There are thousands of regex questions with large scores?

Comment: try putting what you tried, so it does not look like you wait for others to do your work

Comment: If I put what I tried, I would run out of characters, I also don't keep a log of each change I made. I don't use regex often enough to be an expert on it so it was taking me hours to figure this out. all the examples seemed to look for the end of the string. I looked at other peoples questions and quite a lot of well received questions which didn't contain any regex examples of what they had tried. But I will keep in mind to add what I've tried without overwhelming the question.

Comment: You can also link to one of the fiddle/gist like sites with your code, that way you dont overwhelm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with positive lookahead enumerating valid TLDs:

```
(.*?(?=\.(com|co\.uk|net))\.(:?com|co\.uk|net))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ3rFW/1/)

Comment: That's brilliant. Many thanks for this. I was trying to modify an existing email address regex but couldn't get it to work correctly.

Comment: Just be aware that there are lots of possibilities for this to break, e.g. if there is `.net` somewhere else in the email. The more TLDs you add, the higher the chance of hitting one.

Comment: That's fine, I've had to add lots already. It's a one-off project to export recent contacts from Outlook. We had someone doing this manually but this has already allowed me to do 1/3rd of the staff.

Comment: Added (?i) to the beginning to make it non case sensitive.

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Comment: Was using this for C# but will be PHP ultimately.